# Break Out of an ActionResult without Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to do a straight break-out from an ActionResult method?  I'm running some manual verification in my form's submit controller.  If validation fails, I want to exit out of the method.  No redirect, nothing.  Just stop it in it's tracks and exit out.  Something like a break or exit.  Does that exist, or do I have to have a return Redirect()?

Comment: Most examples illustrate that the submit action should validate the input, and if it fails, return a `ViewResult` with `ModelErrorInfo` displayed.  Also, controller actions must return some type of result to the user.  Were you hoping to return 500? :)

Comment: return null or new EmptyResult()?

Comment: `return View(model);`

Comment: The problem with these suggestions is that they just bring up a blank page.  So, the submit button runs the form action.  When it does a return null or return new EmptyResult, it just brings up the form Action in the browser, which is a blank page.  I just want it to stop and stay where it is... or at least refresh the browser with the current info.

Comment: Unclear - why do you refer to `redirect` if any validation failure occurs? A client side validation failure shouldn't even make a request (to any controller) in the first place...

Comment: I'm using server-side validation.  We've had issues with client-side JS-based validation, so we don't want to go that route.

Comment: It might even work if I could just refresh the browser if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code`return View();`
and if you want to return something, you can use strongly typed and return it in the view like the following :

```
return view(model);
```

Comment: This method returns a 404.  The page is loaded by a controller method/view called Admin/CompareItems().  The Form submission action is called Admin/AcceptCompareItems().  So, when I use this method, it redirects to Error/404?aspxerrorpath=/Admin/AcceptCompareItems

Answer (score 0):

Public methods on MVC Controllers and the returning of an ActionResult are abstractions over an HTTP request/response conversation. So if your form is triggering an request, there needs to be a response.

Maybe you should rephrase your question, what it is you actually want to achieve.

Assuming you don't want to render your page again after your manual verification failed, you have the following option:

You could execute the request transfering you form's data in an asynchronous way and thus eliminate the need to redirect or render a full page by using the `@Ajax.BeginForm` method.
Then your controller can return some HTTP status code indicating your failed verification (say, 400 Bad Request) which you react on in clientside JavaScript code.

Example to render an AJAX form in your view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController",
                        new AjaxOptions 
                            { 
                              HttpMethod = "GET",
                              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                              UpdateTargetId = "domElementId",
                              OnSuccess = "JavaScriptFunctionToCall", 
                              OnFailure = "JavaScriptFunctionToCall"}))
{
    @* Put your form inputs here *@
}
```

Comment: Can the response just be "refresh the browser in the state it was when the Action began?"  I mean, if a user is submitting a form and the ActionReusult does some sort of validation, and that validation fails, then obviously the best way to handle that is to break out of the processing so that the user can fix the errors.  In non-MVC web forms, you can just break out of the Button_Click event handler and display a validation summary on the screen.